# Laravel Nova check if admin logged in

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I need to check if Laravel Nova admin is logged in from simple Laravel controller. Default `Auth::check( )` doesnt work here. Is this even possible?

Comment: Can you show the outuput of `php artisan route:list`?

Answer (score 1):

From Nova [documentation site](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/2.0/installation.html#customizing-nova-s-authentication-guard):

> Nova uses the default authentication guard defined in your `auth` configuration file. If you'd like to customize this guard you may set the `guard` value inside of Nova's configuration file.

Also, in production, you need to [customize the way you authorize your users into the Nova admin panel](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/2.0/installation.html#authorizing-nova). This is done in the `gate()` method of your `app/Providers/NovaServiceProvider.php`. For example:

**app/Providers/NovaServiceProvider.php**

```
protected function gate()
{
    Gate::define('viewNova', function ($user) {
        return $user->isAdmin(); // <----
    });
}
```

So, if the logged-in user comply with this conditions (in the example: `$user->isAdmin() == true`), you could say that a "Nova Admin" is logged-in.

Of course, if you've included an ACL system in your app, you could just check if the logged-in user has a specific role (or permission), then this role could serve as validation in the Nova `gate()` function to define which users can access to the admin panel.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There's no built-in concept of an "admin" in Nova. That's up to you. In a stock install, local lets anyone in; in production, it doesn't let *anyone* in.

https://nova.laravel.com/docs/2.0/installation.html#authorizing-nova

You need to look at how your `viewNova` authorization gate is configured, and match that.